# Find the reduction formula for the integral $\int{(a^2-x^2)^n}dx$

Tags: calculus

Let 
$$ u = (a^2-x^2)^{n} \rightarrow du = -2nx(a^2-x^2)^{n-1} $$
and
$$ v = x $$

Now we have, $uv-\int{vdu}$
\begin{align} 
I_n = x(a^2-x^2)^n+2n\int{x^2(a^2-x^2)^{n-1}}dx \tag{1}
\end{align}
But now I have no idea what to do, if I solve the last integral in (1), I only go to 0=0, If I perform integration by parts at the last integral it just gets complicated more.

Comment: Since $x^2=a^2-\left( a^2-x^2\right)$, you can rewrite the integral multiplied by $2n$ as $a^2I_{n-1}-I_n$. Thus $\left( 1+2n\right)I_n = x\left( a^2-x^2\right)^n+2na^2I_{n-1}$.

Comment: @J.G. thank you!